# Can the treble clef be used instead of the bass clef in piano music?

Tags: piano, sheet-music, clefs

I have been learning the piano for a few months now and I am having trouble learning the bass clef. I have played other instruments that use the treble clef so I know it well. Can the bass clef be transformed to the treble clef in piano music? It seems like it would be much easier to read. Is there a compelling reason not to do this? Thanks.

Comment: I guess, transcribing the bass clef to treble clef for some pieces **yourself manually** could be a way for you to learn the bass clef, or at least support your learning process. But don't worry, with more practice than just a few month you'll be able to read bass clef as fluently as the treble clef.

Comment: You could use octave and double octave transposed treble clefs See the images https://musescore.org/en/node/165461 . Or equivalently 8vb 15vb transpose lines. As others have said this is bad from the pedagogic pov.

Comment: Thanks for all the info.  I'm going to continue to learn it.  It's been harder to memorize than I thought it was going to be.

Comment: If you try and fudge things, then you may end up with confusion like this question  https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/51331/why-is-the-treble-clef-in-the-lower-staff-parenthesized

Comment: _"the center of the G clef tells you where G4 is then you know the space below it is an F. From that orientation you then read relative changes."_ As the center of G clef is always at the second line (isn't it?), wouldn't be easier just to think about the position of each note in G clef, never mind where is the center of the clef?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

It is common for piano staff to change clefs. There can be passages with both hands playing G clef or passages with both hands playing F clef. You really need to read both clefs, and getting familiar with C clef is a good idea too.

> Can the bass clef be transformed to the treble clef in piano music?

How can you do this with printed music without re-writing it?

But it makes no sense to put the effort into doing that instead of learning the different clefs.

> Is there a compelling reason not to do this?

Yes, readability.

The reason different clefs exist is so notes can fit conveniently onto a 5 line staff. Below shows what happens if you take notes that fit F clef and then put on a G clef...

[image]

...you get a nightmare of ledger lines. Or, if you transpose up two octaves to get the notes reasonably well centered on G clef and then put an octave line under it, you get something that is kind of misleading appearing to be a scale starting on `A4` rather than `A2`.

Try to read the interval changes rather than line and space letters. So this...

[image]

...should be read like "ascend two thirds, no accidentals" rather than "F A C."

Of course you must be aware of the letters, but it's more like the clef gives you an orientation (the center of the G clef tells you where `G4` is then you know the space below it is an `F`. From that orientation you then read *relative* changes.

Comment: @Rosie F: but if you become fluent just in reading notes on the treble and bass clefs, you will never be able to transpose keys on the fly, while if you become fluent at reading interval changes, you will be able to transpose keys on the fly (although this gets really hard if there are too many accidentals).

Comment: @Rosie, you're exactly right. Reading should be "chunked" and a visual/motor reflex. I didn't mean literally recite intervals in your head.

Answer (score 15):

> Can the bass clef be transformed to the treble clef in piano music?

Yes but please don't.

> It seems like it would be much easier to read.

No. You will be making Middle C be a line in one staff and a space in the other. Bass clef continues directly from treble with middle C being the one ledger line between them.

> Is there a compelling reason not to do this?

Pretty much all piano music uses bass clef. Intentionally ensuring that you can't actually read any music from the instrument you are trying to learn seems like a bad idea.

Answer (score 8):

If you really want to learn to read bass clef, do the opposite of what you are suggesting. Rewrite the treble clef parts in the bass clef, and learn by total immersion. Any music notation software can do this easily.

But spending time playing only the left hand parts of pieces will probably work just as well. Choose pieces where the left hand has plenty of notes to read, not just a few simple chords - for example Bach's two-part inventions.

Comment: https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/31250/how-can-i-learn-to-read-bass-clef-score-more-naturally has some good suggestions as well.

Answer (score 7):

Since generally speaking the bass clef is played with l.h. and treble with r.h., and the hands *are* different, it makes sense that music for piano is written using both clefs. I imagine nearly all piano players would understand and appreciate that.

However, if you wanted to transcribe the bass clef notes so they sat in a treble clef, you could do that. A lot of work, and they'd have to be played at least an octave lower than written - no big deal there - and in the long run, more work than learning the notes in that pesky bass clef.

But you're probably only cofused with note names. Actually, they're just two out from those in the treble clef: the B that's on the middle line, treble, moves to the line below on bass, and retains its name. Not the same B, obviously! But B nevertheless.

Another way to look at it is that the bass clef continues down from where the treble leaves off - leaving a big space for middle C (on its own leger line), whether middle cC is part of the treble or bass clef.

So, yes, it's quite possible, but you'd be doing it for every piece for the rest of your life. Is that really worth it?

Comment: I believe that the exercise of rewriting from the bass clef to the treble clef would probably  help a person to learn to read the bass clef, and at some point they might not feel the need to rewrite to the other clef. In other words, it becomes a learning aid by forcing them to read the lower clef.

Answer (score 6):

Actually the bass clef seamlessly fits below the violin clef, which means, you will recognize a cross-system scale easily.

If you are prepared to write all your scores yourself, this may be an option, but fairly few will be able to play from that.

The bass clef is not *that* difficult, and it is worth the effort to learn it.

Answer (score 2):

If you had to, you could use an octave or double octave clef, like the second one displayed here: [image: Double Octave clefs, demarcated by the '15' notation]

The '15' indicates that symbol is to be read as 2 octaves away (a single octave is represented by an '8'); the direction of which is identified by the position of the number.

The second symbol here with the 15 below the treble clef would be analogous to a bass clef with the notes 2 positions higher. a 'Middle C' on this clef would play as C2, or the C two ledger-lines below the bass stave.

Comment: Eww, is that double-octave-down on an alto clef? Nasty! :)

Comment: None of these are used for piano music.

Answer (score 1):

By convention (at least [since about 1780](https://music.stackexchange.com/a/80465/10162)), piano music is notated with 2 staves in 1 system called the [Grand staff](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Staff_(music)#Grand_staff):

1. the upper staff with the Treble / G clef (for the right hand)
2. the lower staff with the Bass / F clef (for the left hand)

#### Purpose

Before answering your question, let's first understand the *purpose* of the above convention:

1. The piano has 88 keys ranging from A0 to C8, and the approximate center is the Middle C (C4) near where you are seated, and this coincides with how Middle C is notated in BOTH Treble and Bass clefs with just *one* ledger line.  So keys assigned mainly for the right hand (above Middle C) are nicely notated *within* the Treble clef staff lines while keys assigned mainly for the left hand (below Middle C) are nicely notated *within* the Bass clef staff lines, with less frequently used keys needing ledger lines and 8va notation.  See image below ([*source*](https://uh.edu/%7Etkoozin/theory1/clefs/keyboard_full.html)):
   [image: Full keyboard notated]
2. Most frequently used notes in piano music are approximately C2 to C6 which is nicely spread out across the 2 staves as you can see above, requiring at most 2 ledger lines.  It's easier to read notes without ledger lines, so if there are anomalies, engraver would do a "8va" notation or use a clef change in either system.

   For example, to notate the following excerpt from Mozart's piano sonata illustrates how when the left hand plays notes in the higher register, the lower staff is changed to the  treble clef (to avoid excessive ledger lines) until the clef changes to the bass clef again when the left hand's notes are back in the normal register:

   [image: Mozart piano sonata excerpt]

#### Answering your question

Now that we have covered the *purpose* of the Grand Staff convention for notating piano music, I can now answer your question:

> Can the bass clef be transformed to the treble clef in piano music? It seems like it would be much easier to read.

Yes it can, and yes, it would be much easier to read *provided the notes that the left hand is playing fits in the treble clef* as in the Mozart sonata example above.

> Is there a compelling reason not to do this?

Yes, *when the notes that the left hand is playing is mostly below the Middle C*.  Since this convention has been around for a few hundred years, practically every music written for the piano where the two hands need to cover C2 to C6 range (or more), it is easier to read the music when the left hand is notated in the Bass clef.  Therefore, learning how to read piano music notated using the Grand staff is a MUST for serious pianists.